# Flutte error android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart

I am getting below error on android studio.

ProcessException: ProcessException: Process "F:\Flutter Projects\Flutter\login_signup_flutter_test\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.findLauncherJar(BootstrapMainStarter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
  Command: F:\Flutter Projects\Flutter\login_signup_flutter_test\android\gradlew.bat -v

Answer (score 0):

Delete '.gradle' folder in C:\Users***.gradle, connect to internet, rebuild project to download latest Gradle.